# DMOS values in LIVE IQA Database has negative values

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg

I'm working on Image Quality Assessment with LIVE Database. I'm validating a QA algorithm, which is non-linearly dependent on subjective scores (DMOS values). So, I'm trying to fit a curve to find the equation of a curve, I'm taking log on both x and y axes which gives me a linear fit.
But for JPEG Img14 and Img58 have negative DMOS values (-0.19 & -2.64 respectively).

1. What does this mean? Does it mean that JPEG compressed image is better in quality than original image?
2. This is causing me problem while taking log and then using power. How do I fix this issue?